# How to generate a Google graph from date time timestamps from a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, google-visualization

I have a CSV file with datetime timestamps (in milliseconds from 1970) as X axis separed tis a comma ',' and an associated Temperature value as Y axis.

ie :

```html
1485097200000,22.5
1485098100000,23.8
1485099000000,24.2
etc ...
```

From that kind of CSV file i would like to generate a google graph code like this :

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Temperatures');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(1485097200000), 22.5],
    [new Date(1485098100000), 23.8],
    [new Date(1485099000000), 24.2]
  ]);


  var options = {
    title: 'Temperature measured every 15 minutes',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {

      gridlines: {count: 15}
    },
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {color: 'none'},
      minValue: 0
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

  var button = document.getElementById('change');



  button.onclick = function () {

    // If the format option matches, change it to the new option,
    // if not, reset it to the original format.
    options.hAxis.format === 'M/d/yy' ?
      options.hAxis.format = 'MMM dd, yyyy' :
    options.hAxis.format = 'M/d/yy';

    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button id="change">Click to change the format</button>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Would you please tell if it is possible and how i could do it so , i'm newbie.

Regards,

Comment: What the problem to use the code in the jsfiddle? With milliseconds? I'm not sure what miss?

Comment: There is no issue with jsfiffle.net, i only want to know how i could parse datas from a CSV file in order to populate lines into data.addRows([
...
]);  and generate the Google Graph

Comment: check [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38517946/5090771) for using jquery to get the csv and load google charts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for how to get the get the data from a CSV file (in this case come from a string but the principal is the same.

The CSV file should look like this:

```
1486727700000,5\n1486728600000,7\n1486729200000,3\n1486729800000,1\n1486730400000,3\n1486731000000,4\n1486731600000,3\n1486732200000,4\n1486732800000,4
```

Also you need to extract the data from the file so here is the function.

```js
function getData(csv) {
  var output = [];
  csv.split(/\n/).forEach(function(row) {
    var cells = row.split(','),
        date = new Date(parseInt(cells[0])),
        value = parseFloat(cells[1]);

    output.push([date, value]);
  });

  return output;
}
```

And live demo here:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});
// google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Temperatures');

  //   data.addRows([
  //     [new Date(2017, 1, 10, 13, 55), 5],  [new Date(2017, 1, 10, 14, 10), 7],  [new Date(2017,1, 10,14,20), 3],
  //     [new Date(2017, 1, 10, 14, 30), 1],  [new Date(2017, 1, 10, 14,40), 3],  [new Date(2017, 1, 10, 14,50), 4],
  //     [new Date(2017, 1, 10,15,00), 3],  [new Date(2017, 1, 10,15,10), 4],  [new Date(2017, 1, 10,15,20), 2]
  //   ]);

  data.addRows(getData(csvFile));

  var options = {
    title: 'Temperature measured every 15 minutes',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {

      gridlines: {count: 15}
    },
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {color: 'none'},
      minValue: 0
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

  var button = document.getElementById('change');

  button.onclick = function () {

    // If the format option matches, change it to the new option,
    // if not, reset it to the original format.
    options.hAxis.format === 'M/d/yy' ? options.hAxis.format = 'MMM dd, yyyy' : options.hAxis.format = 'M/d/yy';

    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
}

var csvFile = '1486727700000,5\n1486728600000,7\n1486729200000,3\n1486729800000,1\n1486730400000,3\n1486731000000,4\n1486731600000,3\n1486732200000,4\n1486732800000,4';

function getData(csv) {
  var output = [];
  csv.split(/\n/).forEach(function(row) {
    var cells = row.split(','),
        date = new Date(parseInt(cells[0])),
        value = parseFloat(cells[1]);

    output.push([date, value]);
  });

  return output;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<button id="change">Click to change the format</button>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/coxemay

**Update**

How to get the CSV from file using ajax

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart(csvData) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Temperatures');

  getData(function(csvData) {
    data.addRows(csvData);

    var options = {
      title: 'Temperature measured every 15 minutes',
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      hAxis: {

        gridlines: {count: 15}
      },
      vAxis: {
        gridlines: {color: 'none'},
        minValue: 0
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });


  var button = document.getElementById('change');

  button.onclick = function () {

    // If the format option matches, change it to the new option,
    // if not, reset it to the original format.
    options.hAxis.format === 'M/d/yy' ? options.hAxis.format = 'MMM dd, yyyy' : options.hAxis.format = 'M/d/yy';

    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
}

function getData(callback) {
  $.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/moshfeu/e3fd00cb57ae5b5cffbda44422dff112/raw/bcadcdfb5a532cc5711949a60cce639b2da235e6/csv-file', function(csv) {
    var output = [];
    csv.split(/\n/).forEach(function(row) {
      var cells = row.split(','),
          date = new Date(parseInt(cells[0])),
          value = parseFloat(cells[1]);

      output.push([date, value]);
    });

    callback(output);
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<button id="change">Click to change the format</button>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/coxemay/3/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Thank you very much Mosh Feu.

Comment: If the CSV file has a third data on each line, is it possible to draw that one on the graph with a second Y axis ?  I also would like to let the user define by himself the time line range in order to draw a specific part of graph according to a specified time window, user would enter into  2 textboxes first and last date for desired graph . Is these enhancements possible ?

Comment: In your example, you set the csvfile as a variable.  If i have a separe csv file , ie : data.csv that holds the datas what should i modify in the code to let the function load that file first  ?   Should i add something like :    url: 'data.csv',
            type: 'get',
            success:

Comment: `If the CSV file has a third data on each line, is it possible to draw that one on the graph with a second Y axis` I'm not sure I understand. `Is these enhancements possible` Yes. `Should i add something like` As much as I know google doesn't support ajax built-in. Get the data using ajax the way you prefer, then call `drawChart` with the response data.

Comment: Can you please show me how I could load the csv file from an URL and process it afterwards ?

Comment: It works from the CSV file.  Do you know why i can't add to that graph : google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});  This feature would be very usefull for me but looks to be incompatible with 
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});   What did i again wrong ?

Comment: According the docs, you can load the package using this code: `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});`. So my guess is that if you want to load multiple packages just add it to the packages array. Like this: `google.charts.load('current', {'pa3ckages':['corechart', 'annotatedtimeline']});`

Comment: google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'annotatedtimeline']});  does not display the annotated time line, only the graph is displayed.    please see result here : http://output.jsbin.com/vixoqiqasa

Comment: As much as I understand the `annotatedtimeline` is completely different thing. To use this you need to call `new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine` instead of  `new google.visualization.LineChart` and some more changes. Keep attention that you can't use the `lineChart` futures when you using it. http://jsbin.com/viruja/edit?html,js,output Also, you can read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline)

Comment: May i ask another thing please, i need to display the dates in X axis issued from CSV file in 24h format, like this : 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'  . I can't get it working, dates stay in AM PM

Comment: I think that you can't but I'm not sure. You can ask this as different question here on StackOverflow. I'm hoping someone will know the answer for sure.

Comment: @LaurentCoulon If my answer works for your original question please accept it so it could help to other people. Thanks.

Comment: @LaurentCoulon My pleasure :) Do you know [how to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: No, not yet sorry